# Get-Command not behaving as described

Tags: powershell

All the examples I see for `Get-Command` show the results as

```
CommandType    Name   Definition
-----------    ----   ----------
```

Whereas I get:

```
CommandType    Name   Version    Source
-----------    ----   -------    ------
```

I am using Windows 7 with Powershell v5, PSCX,  more details below:

```
PS C:\Users\pollock> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                         
----                           -----                                                         
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117                                                 
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                       
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.117                                                
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                               
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                           
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                           
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats probably because the examples omit the `Source` column. However, you can use the `Select-Object` cmdlet to select the properties you want:

```
Get-Command | Select-Object CommandType, Name, Definition
```

Comment: Thanks. The default behaviour must have changed and the docs/books have not been updated. So ist das Leben.

Comment: Hmm, well if you go to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176842.aspx It suggests that a naked "Get-Command" returns "CommandType    Name   Definition". I was just wondering if I had something weird with my setup. (though to be fair, the text says "That list will look *something like* this:" my emphasis )

Comment: It appears that the documentation you were looking at was current for PS 2.0; it had changed by 4.0 and again in 5.0. That command is not the only Powershell-related documentation that hasn't been updated on the web.

Comment: The documentation here is now open source in Git: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command use the contribute link top right if you think it needs improving and you can do so directly.